# Comparing a lines inside a regular nonagon. How to show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos20^\circ\right)}} = \sqrt{2\left(1-\cos 140^\circ\right)}+1$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am supposed to compare the value of $x$ with the value of $y+z$.

[image]

I've come to the point where I have:
$$x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos20^\circ\right)}} \qquad y+z =  \sqrt{2\left(1-\cos140^\circ\right)}+1$$
Checking with a calculator, both terms seems to be the same, so the relationship should be
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos20^\circ\right)}} = \sqrt{2\left(1-\cos 140^\circ\right)}+1 \quad\to\quad x = y+z$$

> How do I prove the equation is valid using trigonometry? Or, is there another approach to compare the values of $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: Do you know another way to write $1 - \cos\theta,$ for all $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove with trigonometry, apply the identity $2\sin^2 a = 1-\cos 2a$ to

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos20^\circ\right)}}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\sin^210^\circ}}= \frac12\csc 10^\circ \\
\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos140^\circ\right)}+1 & = \sqrt{4\sin^270^\circ}+1 = 2\sin 70^\circ+1\\
&=csc10^\circ (2 \sin70^\circ \sin10^\circ + \sin10^\circ)\\
&= \csc10^\circ (\cos60^\circ -\cos80^\circ + \cos80^\circ)\\
&= \frac12\csc10^\circ
\end{align}

Thus, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos20^\circ\right)}} = \sqrt{2\left(1-\cos 140^\circ\right)}+1$.

Answer (score 4):

The key is to note that the angle between the segment $x$ and one of the sides of the nonagon is $60^\circ$. This allows us to construct an equilateral triangle, just like in the picture. Then we easily calculate that the two marked angles are equal to $40^\circ$ and by SAS the two triangles are congruent --- hence the orange segments are equal. This shows that $x=y+z$.

[image]

Comment: (+1) I know how you did that - you always carry an equilateral triangle hidden up your sleeve! $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use Ptolemy theorem for the quadrilateral whose vertices are the marked points:

[image]

Ptolemy theorem says that $xt=yt+zt$, hence $x=y+z$.

Comment: (+1) Hmmm ... that one's too big to be carried up his sleeve ... how *does* he do it? $\ \ddot\smile$